# In Weaviate GraphQL, how to perform AGGREGATE with WHERE query to find duplicates?

Tags: weaviate

We wanted something similar with PostgreSQL where one can combine `group by` with `having` clause. For example, I want to find `players` with duplicate `player_code`

```
SELECT player_code
FROM public.player
GROUP BY player_code
HAVING COUNT(player_code) > 1;
```

How can I achieve such using [Weaviate Aggregate](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/aggregate)? I only came up with this but could not find a way where to insert the WHERE part?

```
echo '{
  "query": "{
    Aggregate {
      Player(groupBy: [\"player_code\"]) {
        meta {
          count
        }
        groupedBy {
          value
          path
        }
      }
    }
  }"
}' | curl \
    -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d @- \
    http://{{HOST}}/v1/graphql
```

Is this even possible? Perform aggregate query and use the `meta > count` in condition filter (**e.g.,** use meta count `GreaterThan` 1) ?